# MySql Regexp result word part of known word

Tags: mysql, regex

Been struggling for this for awhile.
Is there a way to find all rows in my table where the word in the column 'word' is a part of a search word?

```
+---------+-----------------+
| id_word | word            |
+---------+-----------------+
|  177041 | utvälj          |
|  119270 | fonders         |
|   39968 | flamländarens   |
|   63567 | hänvisningarnas |
|   61244 | hovdansers      |
+---------+-----------------+
```

I want to extract the row 119270, fonders. I want to do this by passing in the word 'plafonders'.

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word REGEXP 'plafonders$'
```

That query will of course not work in this case, would've been perfect if it had been the other way around.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Does the query not return any results? or does it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE 'plafonders' REGEXP concat(word, '$')
```

should accomplish what you want. Your regex:

```
plafonders$
```

is looking for `plafonders` at the end of the column. This is looking for everything the column has until its end, e.g. the regexp is `fonders$` for `119270`.

See https://regex101.com/r/Ytb3kg/1/ compared to https://regex101.com/r/Ytb3kg/2/.

Comment: Works like a charm!:)

Comment: Like a charm -- until the table gets big.  This query always scans the entire table.

Comment: @RickJames The OP wants to compare the input against a loose `word` match, how can it be done without a full table scan? I see your answer below but that too requires a full table scan to evaluate the `word`, no?

Comment: @chris85 - I can think of two ways to do it without a full table scan, but they are messy - one requires storing the reversed spelling of `word` (in an indexed column); the other requires trying substrings until one works.

Comment: @RickJames Yea, the inverse method seems like a huge mess. The substring method also seems like it'd be close, if not greater than ( in execution time) this approach.

Comment: @chris85 - the substring approach would require a looping through the length of `'plafonders'`.  SQL is not friendly to loops.  But if there are millions of rows, the loop could use a fast index.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `REGEXP` does not handle accented letters very well.  Perhaps it will work OK in your limited situation.

Here's a slightly faster approach (though it still requires a table scan):

```
SELECT * FROM words
    WHERE   'PLAutvälj' =
      RIGHT('PLAutvälj', CHAR_LENGTH(word)) = word;
```

(To check the accents, I picked a different word from your table.)